# Why is SQL converting Varchar value to Integer in a varchar column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am receiving an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int

while trying to insert data from one table into another. Both have the same table structure (table being inserted is an exact copy of the one used in the `Select`) and data types on the columns are the same.

```
INSERT INTO PS_PSOPRDEFN_BA
    SELECT * 
    FROM PSOPRDEFN
```

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '11000_600' to data type int.

The column this is inserting with this value is a `varchar(30)` in both tables, so I don't know why SQL is trying to convert it to `int`. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: 11000_600 how it converts '-' into int?

Comment: Can you share the schema of both the  tables and the sample data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: somehow the column order was changed, even though I performed an exact copy of the underlying table. Think I've figured it out now.

Answer (score 2):

When doing inserts, *always* include the columns:

```
INSERT INTO PS_PSOPRDEFN_BA ( . . . )  -- column list here
    SELECT . . .  -- column list here
    FROM PSOPRDEFN;
```

You have a value which is a string which is being assigned to an integer column, and the value cannot be converted.

When doing an `insert`, the columns are aligned by order in the column list, not by name.  So, merely having the same name doesn't mean that the code will work.  The tables have to have exactly the same columns defined in the same order with compatible types for your code to work.